# Append to dictionary in defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict, I want to create a dictionary as the value part, can I append to this dictionary? At the moment I am appending to a list which means that the dictionaries are separated.

```
dates = [datetime.date(2016, 10, 17), datetime.date(2016, 10, 18), datetime.date(2016, 10, 19), datetime.date(2016, 10, 20), datetime.date(2016, 10, 21), datetime.date(2016, 10, 22), datetime.date(2016, 10, 23)]

e = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    value = (sorted(value, key=itemgetter('date'), reverse=False))
    for date in dates:
        for i in value:
            if i['date'] == str(date) and i['time'] == 'morning':
                value1 = float(i['value1'])
                temp = {'val_morning': value1 }
                e[str(date)].append(temp)
            elif ii['date'] == str(date) and i['time'] == 'evening':
                value2 = float(i['value2'])
                temp = {'val_evening': value2 }
                e[str(date)].append(temp)
```

which results in:

```
{'2016-10-20': [{'val_morning': 0.0}, {'val_evening': 0.0}], '2016-10-21': [{'val_morning': 0.0}, {'val_evening': 0.0}]}
```

**Edit**
desired output:

```
{                        
    '2016-10-20': {'val_morning': 0.0, 'val_evening': 0.0}, 
    '2016-10-21': {'val_morning': 0.0, 'val_evening': 0.0}
}
```

Comment: Why does your desired output contain a list that always only has one item?  It seems that the list is unnecessary -- Wouldn't `{'2016-10-20': {'value1': 0.0, 'value2': 0.0}, '2016-10-21': ...` be better?

Comment: agreed, scrap the list. will update the question. thanks

Comment: Are there always going to be only 2 values per day (one for morning corresponding to `value1` and one for evening corresponding to `value2`)?  Or could there be more values in a day?  What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: sorry - there could be more, i jsut want a dict containing the values for each day

Comment: Your code looks like it is appending dicts of the format `{'val': value}` but you're reporting output that has dicts that look like `{'value1': 0.0}` -- Are you reporting the output of `e` or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You are using `for date in dates:` but I do not see the value of `dates` defined in your code. What is it's content?

Comment: Your new desired output is `list` of `dict`? I think you need `dict` of `dict`

Comment: @user3939059 -- "I just want a dict containing the values for each day" -- This is super ambiguous.  how does that mesh with the "morning" and "evening" tests that you're doing?  Do you want to discard that information and just have a dictionary that maps a date to a list of floating point values?  `{'2016-10-20': [0.0, 0.0, ...], ...}`?

Comment: dates is just a list of dates, i have added it to the question. dict of dict would be great

Comment: @mgilson, the tests (morning/evening) that i am doing correspond to the field names and values that i set when i append. they don't actually make a difference to the dict i am trying to create. i have just created these dummy field names and values for the purpose of this question

Comment: @user3939059: Based on your comment: *dict of dict would be great*, made and edit to your desired output, because I think this is what you want. Feel free to roll it back in case this is not what you desire.

Comment: sorry didn't realise you were editing - i only changed the variable names to make it clear about the morning/evening misunderstanding. let me check i havent made a mess of your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood you correctly, you want to replace the list with a dict, that you can later add to it values.

if so you can do this:

```
dates = [datetime.date(2016, 10, 17), datetime.date(2016, 10, 18), datetime.date(2016, 10, 19), datetime.date(2016, 10, 20), datetime.date(2016, 10, 21), datetime.date(2016, 10, 22), datetime.date(2016, 10, 23)]

e = defaultdict(dict)
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    value = (sorted(value, key=itemgetter('date'), reverse=False))
    for date in dates:
        for i in value:
            if i['date'] == str(date) and i['time'] == 'morning':
                value1 = float(i['value1'])
                temp = {'val_morning': value1 }
                e[str(date)].update(temp) #### HERE i replaced append with update!
            elif ii['date'] == str(date) and i['time'] == 'evening':
                value2 = float(i['value2'])
                temp = {'val_evening': value2 }
                e[str(date)].update(temp)#### HERE i replaced append with update!
```

i simply replaced the append with [update](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) (and of course made the defaultdict use dict instead of list)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly

```
import datetime
dates = [datetime.date(2016, 10, 17), datetime.date(2016, 10, 18), datetime.date(2016, 10, 19), datetime.date(2016, 10, 20), datetime.date(2016, 10, 21), datetime.date(2016, 10, 22), datetime.date(2016, 10, 23)]

dict_x = {}
for i in map(str,set(dates)):
    dict_x[i] = {'val_morning': 0.0, 'val_evening': 0.0}

dict_x

output :
{'2016-10-17': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0},
 '2016-10-18': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0},
 '2016-10-19': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0},
 '2016-10-20': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0},
 '2016-10-21': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0},
 '2016-10-22': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0},
 '2016-10-23': {'val_evening': 0.0, 'val_morning': 0.0}}
```